# VBA: Convert all worksheet text to number

Tags: vba, excel, type-conversion

I'm looking to to convert automatically all number stored as text in worksheet to numbers with VBA. Excel seems to detect automatically theses values, there is a way in VBA to convert all theses numbers ?

[image: Excel detect automatically numbers stored as text]

I found this following solution to convert a text to a number, but i want this apply to all the worksheet and not to a specify Range, because the worksheet is dynamic.

```
Range("F:F").Select
With Selection
    Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
.Value = .Value
End With
```

Somebody have an idea ?

Comment: Is the problem due to the fact, that you are working with `.` as decimal separator? Thus the `,` is not recognized and Excel formats it automatically as `Text`?

Comment: Thanks you, it was that !

Comment: This problem is happening in Germany quite often, I guess in France it should be the case as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
with activesheet.usedRange
    .numberFormat = "General"
    .value = .value
End with
```

Answer (score 1):

Guessing that the problem is in the different decimal separator, which is quite a big problem in Germany and France. If this is the case, this works:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    On Error GoTo TestMe_Error

    Dim myCell As Range
    Dim tryCell As String

    For Each myCell In Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        tryCell = Replace(myCell, ",", ".")
        If IsNumeric(tryCell) Then
            myCell = Replace(myCell, ",", ".")
        End If
    Next myCell

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

TestMe_Error:

    MsgBox "No contant values!"

End Sub
```

The code checks all the cells without formula in the `ActiveSheet`. Then, if by changing the `,` to a `.` the cell would become numeric, it changes it.